# Uninstall a REPO [yum]

Tags: redhat, yum

I am using a RedHat 6.3 system.

- I had an issues installing php-mcrypt
- Hence I updated by epel version to 6.5.
- yum update said (error: try check your path and try again)
- there was a firewall, so I disabled it
- I wanted to reinstall the repo so I deleted epel.repo and epel-testing.repo
- And tried to install it again, the following message shows up

Message:

```
Setting up Install Process
Examining epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm: epel-release-6-5.noarch
epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
```

Is there something I am missing ?

Also when I try installing the repo via rpm

```
rpm -i epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm 
warning: epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0608b895: NOKEY
package epel-release-6-5.noarch is already installed
```

Answer (score 6):

From the error you're getting and the steps you've performed so far it seems to me like you didn't uninstall the RPM so it's still in the RPM database. Try running:

```
rpm -qa | grep epel
```

or

```
rpm -qi epel-release-6-5
```

and see what you get. If either of these returns details relating to the RPM you installed, then you'll need to actually remove the RPM, then re-install it, removing the files alone won't do the job. If this doesn't return an output, there could be something wrong with your RPM database, in which case I would suggest you remove /var/lib/rpm/__db* (ONLY AFTER BACKING UP THOSE FILES). Then rebuild the rpm database (as a privileged user) with:

```
rpm --rebuilddb
```

That should get the DB rebuilt and updated.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer was correct could you please mark it as such?